# I can load my rails app to heroku, but when I use heroku open I get an Application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, heroku, github

I tried to upload my rails app to heroku. It said it uploaded but when I do command heroku open it I'm getting an Application Error. Also when I used the command git push heroku master everything seemed fine until I looked at the command line and it said

warning removing gemfile.lock because it was generated on windows

not sure what to do next

here is my heroku logs if that helps

```
2013-08-16T01:34:12.958718+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by lanners.marshall
@yahoo.com
2013-08-16T01:34:12.972553+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by lanners.mars
hall@yahoo.com
2013-08-16T01:34:37+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-08-16T01:36:16.357352+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by lanners.marshall
@yahoo.com
2013-08-16T01:36:23.022294+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COPPER re
source by lanners.marshall@yahoo.com
2013-08-16T01:36:23.048343+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by lanners.mars
hall@yahoo.com
2013-08-16T01:36:23.108934+00:00 heroku[api]: Add DATABASE_URL config by lanners
.marshall@yahoo.com
2013-08-16T01:36:23.134903+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by lanners.mars
hall@yahoo.com
2013-08-16T01:36:23.186940+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e3e9c0c by lanners.marshall
@yahoo.com
2013-08-16T01:36:23.217579+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by lanners.mars
hall@yahoo.com
2013-08-16T01:36:23+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-08-16T01:36:28.240140+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-08-16T01:36:28.241577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-08-16T01:36:36.751238+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-08-16T01:38:10.407842+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=frozen-reef-1255.herokuapp.com fwd="107.20.71.243"
```

here also is a copy of my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
ruby '1.9.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try migrating the database on heroku like this:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: oh hey I did that command and it said /user/bin/env: ruby.exe No such file or directory. Not sure what that means I feel confused.

Comment: you ran that in your cmd promt in the same app folder?

Comment: oh ya I ran it in the cmd promt in the same app folder. Not sure why its happening ?